# joining two tables, select values from two with second table having no records

Tags: mysql

I have two tables where i fetch values from both tables, the situation is the first table always contains records but second table may or maynot.

here are tables

`TAB1

id | rank
1  | TL
2  | PL
3  | MG

TAB2

num | id | swiped_on
1   |  1 | 20-4-14
2   |  1 | 21-4-14
3   |  3 | 25-4-14`

the result i want is,(only one record from the second table)

`id | rank | swiped_on
 1  |  TL  | 21-4-14
 2  |  PL  | -------
 3  |  MG  | 25-4-14`

please help

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already.

Comment: SELECT a.id,a.rank,b.swiped_on FROM TAB1 a, TAB2 b where b.id=a.id group by a.id order by b.swiped_on DESC -- this works only if there is record in second table

Comment: This is a mess. See normalisation. And don't use implicit (comma-) join syntax. Use proper JOIN syntax instead. Then your problem will be half solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left join with a subselect from table tab2

```
select t.*,t1.swiped_on
from TAB1 t
left join (select id , max(swiped_on) swiped_on
          from TAB2 group by id
          ) t1
on(t.id = t1.id)
```

### [`Fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e8b7/1)

Or just get the max of swiped_on from tab2

```
select t.*,max(t1.swiped_on) swiped_on
from TAB1 t
left join TAB2 t1
on(t.id = t1.id)
group by t.id
```

### [`Fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e8b7/2)